# Mechanize 'link_with' producing a different URL

Tags: ruby, liferay, mechanize, portlet

I accessed a page that has this link:

```
<a class="portletpage-portlet-title is-active" tabindex="0" title="Registration" data-ppid="registration_WAR_registration" href="#registration">Registration</a>
```

The page is encrypted with SSL. The HTML attribute `href` is `#registration`. I am trying to follow this link get to the URL:

```
www.redacted.com/#registration
```

Here is my code:

```
agent.get('*redacted*'). do |page|
page.form_with(:action => '*redacted*') do |f|
    f.field_with(:id => 'username').value = get_username()
    f.field_with(:id => 'password').value = get_password()
end.click_button

agent.page.link_with(:text => 'Registration').click
```

When it clicks on the link, it produces the following error:

```
`fetch': 404 => Net::HTTPNotFound for https://*redacted*/group/1403104853945/academics?p_p_id=registration_WAR_uofsregistration&p_p_state=maximized -- unhandled response (Mechanize::ResponseCodeError)
    from /home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:464:in `get'
    from /home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize.rb:348:in `click'
    from /home/mike/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/page/link.rb:30:in `click'
    from u-of-s-scraper.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

and comes up with the URL:

```
www.redacted.com/group/1403104853945/academics?p_p_id=registration_WAR_uofsregistration&p_p_state=maximized
```

I'm not sure where Mechanize is getting the URL. The link has an attribute `data-ppid`, which appears to be contributing to the URL. Can anyone provide some insight?

It turns out that the page is written using Liferay's Portlets. Unfortunately, Portlets are not directly URL accessible, so I am currently investigating a different means of scraping the page - potentially with Selenium or PhantomJS.

Answer (score 0):

`data-ppid` is a data attribute, which is supposed to be handled by JavaScript. The change of the URL is probably due to some Javascript code on the client side (and a redirect on the server side).

Answer (score 0):

Links that start with # are "named links" or "bookmark links" - they don't go anywhere, just jump you somewhere on the page.

In other words, there's no reason to ever "follow" a link like that with mechanize.